# Is setting the DEFAULT CHARSET in MySQL necessary when creating databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Just finished a course going over some topics in MySQL and using SQL in general and I noticed that they set the CHARSET DEFAULT when creating the database.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbName **DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;**
```

The course never touched on that and I haven't done anything like that yet, just wondering if that is a common standard when creating databases in DBMSs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's optional.

If you don't specify a character set, the database will still have a default, it will just be a "default default" which it takes from the value of MySQL's `character_set_server` configuration variable.

The database default character set is ignored if you specify a table's character set when you CREATE TABLE. In other words, if you don't rely on the default, but specify one for each table.

In MySQL 8.0, the out-of-the-box default for `character_set_server` is finally utf8mb4, which is recommended. So you shouldn't need to specify the character set when you create a database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, good to hear that utf8mb4 is the default now!